# Passing Json from action to view by ViewBag

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jsonresult

I'm trying to get the result below using `JsonResult`, but I can't

```
var localJSON = [

            { "id": "1", "label": "tagName1", "value": "tagValue1" },
                { "id": "2", "label": "tagName2", "value": "tagValue2" },
                { "id": "3", "label": "tagName3", "value": "tagValue3" },
                { "id": "1553", "label": "tagName1553", "value": "tagValue1553" }
    ];
```

Here is the way I use:

**controller**

```
private JsonResult GetAvailableTags()
        {
            var tagsList = Facade.Tags.Get(CurrentLocale.ID);
            var retValue = new
            {
                id = tagsList.Select(x => x.ID).ToArray(),
                label = tagsList.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray(),
                value = tagsList.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray()
            };
            return Json(retValue);
        }
public ActionResult AddPhoto()
        {

            var availblableTags = GetAvailableTags();
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            ViewBag.AvailableTags = serializer.Serialize(availblableTags.Data);
            return View();
        }
```

**view**

```
var localJSON = [ @Html.Raw(ViewBag.AvailableTags)];
```

The result is

```
var localJSON = [
   {"id":[1,2,3,1553],"label":["tagName1","tagName2","tagName3","tagName1553" ],"value":["tagName1","tagName2","tagName3","tagName1553" ]}
        ];
```

What should I do to resolve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to get `x.Value` for `value` in JSON? Then change your assignment for `retValue` to

```
var retValue = tagsList.Select(
    x => new 
    { 
        id = x.Id, 
        label = x.Name, 
        value = x.Value 
    }).ToArray();
```

In your `retValue` assignment code you were creating a single object of anonymous type with array-typed members id, label and value. For the output you want you need to create an array, each member of which is an object with simple fields id, name and value.