# Pass model data to view's javascript as json object via ViewBag

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, object, serialization

I have sat here all day trying to figure this out. I am working with asp.net MVC 4 and using the Entity framework.

Controller

```
private JsonResult GetRegion()
    {
        var ctrys = new inmsEntities().Regions.ToList().Select(
            c => new
            {
                c.Id,
                c.Name

            }).ToArray();

        return Json(ctrys);

    }

[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        BasicForm someform= new BasicForm()
        var reg= GetRegion();
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        ViewBag.Reg= serializer.Serialize(reg.Data);


        return View(someform);
    }
```

View

```
var allregions = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Reg);
alert(allregions);
```

This view renders as

```
var allregions = [{"id": 1,"Countryid": 1,"Name": "Foo"},{"id": 2,"Countryid": 1,"Name": "Bar"}];
alert(allregions);
```

But the `alert(allregions);` pops up as

```
[object Object Object],[Object Object Object]
```

I am passing a form to the view and i need to populate an array with corresponding regions if user select a countryid in the form. I plan to loop through the json object for countryid == ? and create an array of corresponding regions. However I am stuck at representing the model as a parsable json object. What am doing wrong ? I got this method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427635/passing-json-from-action-to-view-by-viewbag)

Comment: Do not alert things like arrays and objects. Use console.log(allregions) instead.